# Docusaurus font loading for text but not headings

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend

In my Docusaurus custom CSS file I have this code:

```
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap");
:root {
    --ifm-color-primary: #25c2a0;
    --ifm-color-primary-dark: #29784c;
    --ifm-color-primary-darker: #277148;
    --ifm-color-primary-darkest: #205d3b;
    --ifm-color-primary-light: #33925d;
    --ifm-color-primary-lighter: #359962;
    --ifm-color-primary-lightest: #3cad6e;
    --ifm-code-font-size: 95%;
    --docusaurus-highlighted-code-line-bg: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

This code is changing the regular text on my site, but it isn't changing headings. When I inspect the headings I see that the Montserrat font is crossed out, indicating that it is being overridden somewhere. Are heading styles set anywhere by default with Docusaurus?

Answer (score 0):

You should add something like

```
  --ifm-font-family-base: Montserrat, 'Montserrat';
```

to override Infima CSS variables globally, see https://docusaurus.io/docs/styling-layout#styling-your-site-with-infima